# Solve for $x$: $n|\sin x|=m|\cos x|$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for $x$ using graphs: $$n|\sin x|=m|\cos x|$$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n>m$.

I am getting infinite solutions. Please help.

Comment: Please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to format equations. What is wrong with there being an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: sine and cosine are both $2\pi$ periodic so if $x$ is a solution, so is $x + 2\pi$ and $x - 2\pi$ and $x + 4\pi$ and $x + 6\pi$, etc.

Comment: The condition $n>m$ is quasi irrelevant because it can be rewritten $-n<-m$, where $-m,-n\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a purely analytic approach, but I hope you find this interesting.

First, if $\cos x=0$, then $\sin x=\pm 1$. You then have $n =0$, which is a solution.

Then, if you write it as $|\sin x/\cos x|=|\tan x|$, you are looking for $x$ such that $\tan x$ is rational and smaller than $1$ because you want $n>m$. This occurs only in cases of a pythagorean triple. Let us recall Euclid's pythagorean triples formula.

> **Euclid's formula**: All pythagorean triples are generated by
>   $$a=k\cdot (m^{2}-n^{2}),\ \,b=k\cdot (2mn),\ \,c=k\cdot (m^{2}+n^{2})$$
>   where $m$, $n$, and $k$ are positive integers with $m > n$, and with $m$ and $n$ coprime and not both odd.

Then, for a pythagorean triple, we see that the tangent is given by
$$\tan x=\dfrac{2mn}{m^2-n^2}$$
for positive, coprime integers $m>n$. Since these are the only solutions for a rational tangent, and that you want $2mn>m^2-n^2$, let $f$ be
$$f(m)=m^2-2mn-n^2=(m-(1+\sqrt{2})n)(m-(1-\sqrt{2})n).$$
Then it is negative only if
$$n(1-\sqrt{2})<m<n(1+\sqrt{2})$$
which is equivalent to $2mn>m^2-n^2$.

In summary, to generate your solutions, you first take $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, you look for all coprime integers $m$ such that $n<m<n(1+\sqrt{2})$. You thus have the solution 
$$x=\pm\arctan\left(\dfrac{2mn}{m^2-n^2}\right).$$
By construction, you have all $x$ which are a solution to your problem.

Comment: What is the benefit of this approach over the straightforward $x=\pm\arctan m/n$ ?

Comment: The straighfoward approach gives rise to some redundant solutions. For example, you could have $q_1,q_2$ two rationals such that they respect the conditions stated and giving out the same $x$. This slightly more complicated approach gives an algorithm which generates no duplicates. Therefore, it might save some memory/computing time for example.

Comment: In case full enumeration would be requested ? ;-)

Comment: Exactly! The actual question isn't really clear regarding the objective of this computation. I assumed that full enumeration was asked. On the flip side, I really had fun writing this solution, and I hope you had fun reading it too :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this its best to consider separate cases so that you can divide through by $|\cos x|$.

If $m=0, n\neq0$, then $\sin x=0$, so $x=k\pi\,\,,\,k\in\mathbb{R}$

If $m\neq0, n=0$, then $\cos x=0$, so $x=(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi\,\,,\,k\in\mathbb{R}$

If $m\neq0, n\neq0$, then $|\cos x|\neq0$.

Then you can divide both sides by $n|\cos x|$, so you get $|\tan x|=\frac{m}{n}$.

You then need to consider the cases which depend on the signs of $m$ and $n$.

Now you can sketch the graphs of each case.

---

As you'll see, there are an infinite number of solutions in some cases which is completely fine.

Comment: "$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})\sin x \neq \cos x$": are you sure ?

Comment: By the way, your lengthy discussion can be made shorter. If $\cos x=0$, then $\sin x\ne 0$ and the equation has no solution unless $n=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Nope, I'm definitely not. Tnx lol

Answer (score 0):

The equation is

$$\tan x=\pm\frac mn,$$ assuming that $m,n$ have the same sign ($\cos x=0$ cannot be a solution, unless $n=0$, which we do not consider).

The solution is then $$x=\pm\arctan\frac mn+k\pi.$$